# How to cuszomize Azure B2C templates without injecting form controls generated by B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I want to customize an html page in azure B2C without having to inject HTML Form Controls generated by Azure B2C.
The authentication journey is the following:

3. I call an API. The API returns a claim "scopes_to_approve" of type "string" or "stringcollection"
4. I display the missing scopes using a custom html template (custom contentDefinition) which should look like this:
   APP xxx wants to:

- Read your identity
- Manage your xxx data

As I understand, the only way to use B2C claims in a template is by injecting the div api element. This element will contain FormControls generated by the B2C Framework.

> ```
> <div id="api"></div>
> ```

Then I have to do DOM manipulations in order to achieve what I want. And those manipulations will be executed on client side. Am I right?

I would have expected :

- avoid having to inject HTML B2C form controls in order to use claims
- Have an advanced HTML B2C server side generator template (server pre-processed rendering)
- OR:
- Having the possibility to use the claims from javascript with that kind of code:

> ```
> $("meta[property='my_claim']");
> ```

- OR:
- at worst having a "hidden" UserInputType claim in the injected api element

Am I right? Is there any other possibility?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to return a string to the page in the div generated by AAD B2C. And have AAD B2C render a text box to record what the user selected. Take the string which is in the b2c div textbox that has the REST API returned values and use some JS to render some controls client side on the page. Based on what the user selects, return data through the second text box that AAD B2C rendered. You can hide both text boxes with CSS.

There is a sample here:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/selectemail